# How to locally unset (org-clock-into-drawer t)

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

Is there a possibility to locally unset the clocking location variable org-clock-into-drawer?
I'd like to have clocking tucked away most of the time in some drawers. But for my general tracking file I do not want to clock into a drawer

Enabling clocking behavior globally

```
(setq org-drawers (quote ("PROPERTIES" "LOGBOOK")))     ;; Separate drawers for clocking and logs
(setq org-clock-into-drawer t)    ;; Save clock data and state changes and notes in the LOGBOOK drawer
```

will result in something like this:

```
* Maintenance  
:LOGBOOK:  
CLOCK: [2014-10-16 Thu 08:48]--[2014-10-16 Thu 09:08] =>  0:20
CLOCK: [2014-10-15 Wed 08:51]--[2014-10-15 Wed 09:01] =>  0:10
CLOCK: [2014-10-14 Tue 08:40]--[2014-10-14 Tue 08:45] =>  0:05
CLOCK: [2014-10-13 Mon 08:41]--[2014-10-13 Mon 08:59] =>  0:18
:END:
```

I want to unset the behavior for particular files. Based on [Clocking-commands](http://orgmode.org/manual/Clocking-commands.html#Clocking-commands) I expect something like `#+PROPERTY CLOCK_INTO_DRAWER: nil` to result in the following output

```
* Maintenance  
CLOCK: [2014-10-16 Thu 08:48]--[2014-10-16 Thu 09:08] =>  0:20
CLOCK: [2014-10-15 Wed 08:51]--[2014-10-15 Wed 09:01] =>  0:10
CLOCK: [2014-10-14 Tue 08:40]--[2014-10-14 Tue 08:45] =>  0:05
CLOCK: [2014-10-13 Mon 08:41]--[2014-10-13 Mon 08:59] =>  0:18
```

But it seems not to work as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems like a bug to me. You should be able to override
`org-clock-into-drawer` with

```
#+PROPERTY: CLOCK_INTO_DRAWER nil
```

Note that the above line is slightly different than what you used, but
it still won't work. The issue is with the function
`org-clock-into-drawer`. I'll send these changes to the Org mode list,
but if you want to get this working on your end immediately, the
following patch should fix the issue.

```
diff --git c/lisp/org-clock.el w/lisp/org-clock.el
index 2ffcbfa..092a6aa 100644
--- c/lisp/org-clock.el
+++ w/lisp/org-clock.el
@@ -74,13 +74,15 @@ (defun org-clock-into-drawer ()
 it will be used instead of the default value.
 The default is the value of the customizable variable `org-clock-into-drawer',
 which see."
-  (let ((p (org-entry-get nil "CLOCK_INTO_DRAWER" 'inherit))
-   (q (org-entry-get nil "LOG_INTO_DRAWER" 'inherit)))
-    (cond
-     ((or (not (or p q)) (equal p "nil") (equal q "nil")) org-clock-into-drawer)
-     ((or (equal p "t") (equal q "t")) "LOGBOOK")
-     ((not p) q)
-     (t p))))
+  (let ((p (org-entry-get nil "CLOCK_INTO_DRAWER" 'inherit t))
+        (q (org-entry-get nil "LOG_INTO_DRAWER" 'inherit t)))
+    (cond ((equal p "nil") nil)
+          ((equal p "t") t)
+          (p)
+          ((equal q "nil") nil)
+          ((equal q "t") t)
+          (q)
+          (t org-clock-into-drawer))))

 (defcustom org-clock-out-when-done t
   "When non-nil, clock will be stopped when the clocked entry is marked DONE.
```

**Edit:** I've updated the patch based on [this discussion](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/91836). The fix is in commit [70e0b08e](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=70e0b08e6632ec5d437dcd05db14a698bbc9489d).

Comment: Great! I applied the patch and that really solved my problem. Thanks, Stefan

Comment: FYI, I just tried the property setting in Emacs 26.1 and org-mode 9.1.9 and it worked correctly, so your patch must have made it into the releases.  Though, I must say this change in default behavior is quite infuriating!